# Is it possible to use a file as Filesystem?

Tags: lvm, ext4, lxc, snapshot, lxd

Here is the origin of my question:

- I'm running Linux containers with LXD snap version at Ubuntu 22.04 on a VPS. The root file system of the VPS is Ext4 and there is not additional storage attached. So the default LXD storage pool is created by the *dir* option.
- When I'm taking a snapshots of these LXCs, the whole data is duplicated - i.e. the if the container is 6G the snapshot become another 6G.
- I think if it was LVM filesystem the snapshots will be created in a different way.

So my question is:

- It possible to do something like `fallocate -l 16G /lvm.fs`, then format it as LVM, mount it and use it as storage pool for LXD? And of course, how can I do that if it is possible?

---

Some notes:

The solution provided by @larsks works as it is expected! Later I found, when we are using `lxc storage create pool-name lvm` without additional options and parameters, it does almost the same. I didn't test it before I published the question because I was thinking the `lvm` driver mandatory will require be in use a separate partition.

However in both cases this approach, in my opinion, has much more cons than pros, for example:

- The write speed is decreased with about 10% in comparison of the  cases when we are using the `dir` driver.
- Hard to recover situations when no space left on the *disk*, even when the overload data is located in `/tmp`... in contrast, when the `dir` driver is used, LXD prevents the consumption of the entire host's file system space, so your system and containers are still operational. This is much conviniant in my VPS case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It possible to do something like fallocate -l 16G /lvm.fs, then format it as LVM, mount it and use it as storage pool for LXD? And of course, how can I do that if it is possible?

Start by making your file. I like to place it in a directory other than `/`, so I created a `/vol` directory for this purpose:

```
truncate -s 16G /vol/pv0
```

(As @LustreOne notes in comments, using `truncate` rather than
`fallocate` doesn't preallocate blocks for the file, so it starts out
using zero bytes and only consumes as much disk space as is written to
it).

Configure that file as a block device using `losetup`:

```
losetup -fnP --show /vol/pv0
```

That will output the name of a loop device (probably `/dev/loop0`, but if not, adjust the following commands to match).

Set up LVM on that device:

```
pvcreate /dev/loop0
vgcreate vg0 /dev/loop0
lvcreate ...
```

Congratulations, you have a filed-backed LVM VG!

Unfortunately, if you were to reboot at this point, you would find that the VG was missing: loop devices aren't persistent, so we need to add some tooling to configure things when the system starts up.

Put the following into `/usr/local/bin/activate-vg.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

losetup -fnP /vol/pv0
vgchange -ay
```

And make sure it's executable:

```
chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/activate-vg.sh
```

Add a systemd unit to activate the service. Put the following into `/etc/systemd/system/activate-vg.service`:

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Requires=local-fs.target local-fs-pre.target
After=local-fs-pre.target
Before=local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/activate-vg.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
```

Enable the service:

```
systemctl enable activate-vg
```

Now your file-backed LVM VG should be available when you reboot.

Comment: Note that fallocate will force allocation of the full space. If you use "truncate -s" to set the file size (sparse file), the file will only use as much space as was actually written to it.

Comment: @LustreOne good point, I just used `fallocate` because that's what the OP was using, but I'll edit this to use `truncate`.